# How do I safeguard that addChild(x) isn't added twice?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I keep running into a problem where `addChild(myLabel)` is triggered twice, resulting in a crash. Is there a way to safeguard that `addChild(myLabel)` isn't triggered if it has already added the `label`?

I was looking for a `bool`, something like `myLabel.isAddedToView` but don't think there is one. I also tried

```
guard let test = addChild(myLabel) else {print("error") return}
```

But this gives me the error

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not Void'

Comment: Show us the structure of your code.  You should not be safeguarding against it, you should be writing code to not even allow a second pass to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping track of that in a boolean, like

```
var isChildAdded = false

if !isChildAdded {
    addChild(myLabel)
    isChildAdded = true
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against this.  You have an even bigger problem logically.  This is like placing a bandaid on a gunshot wound.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean usage of this function `addChild(_ childController: UIViewController)` 
then I would suggest to check by

`if !controller.children.contains(controller1) { 
// your actions 
}`

Otherwise if it is `addSubview(_ view: UIView)` then

`if !view1.subviews.contains(view2) {
//your actions
}`

Comment: This is SpriteKit, not UIKit